# How to Force Django's urls.py regex to restrict to ASCII digits only?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have the following entry in my urls.py:

```
url(r'^\d{2}/$', 'test.view'),
```

I obviously want to match 2 digits only, so 12 is good, 23 is good, but 123 is not, and this works beautifully.

However, when I try Arabic digits alongside English ones, like 2٢ or 4٤, it matches, but I don't want that behavior! The digit 2٤ for example results in the following request:

```
http://localhost/2%D9%A4
```

I definitely do not want that. How to make Django URL CONF only accept normal ascii digits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\d` matches any digits, including Arabic ones. Just use `[0-9]` instead:

```
url(r'^[0-9]{2}/$', 'test.view'),
```

Quote from [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> \d
>
> When the UNICODE flag is not specified, matches any decimal digit;
>   this is equivalent to the set [0-9]. With UNICODE, it will match
>   whatever is classified as a decimal digit in the Unicode character
>   properties database.

`٢` and `٤`, for example, are Unicode decimal digits:

```
>>> u'٤'.isdigit()
True
>>> u'٢'.isdigit()
True
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: You are welcome, I've added some notes for better understanding what is going on.